# 6502 assembly shift bits

Tags: assembly, 6502

I have a number `1f` stored at address `00`, and I have another number `1e` stored at address `01`. Now I want to make `1f` into `1f00` and `1e` into `001e`, then add them up to get `1f1e`. How do I do this? I know the instructions `asl` and `lsr` deal with this, but I'm a 6502 beginner, so I would really appreciate it someone can show me how it's done efficiently(least amount of cycles).

Comment: Since 6502 is a 8 bit machine, you can't work with 16 bit numbers directly. You can just manipulate the two halves separately, no shifts needed.

Comment: @Jester Do you mean that if I want to store something into `1f1e` I need to use `sta ($00),y`?

Comment: Yes, but remember that 6502 is little endian, so to get `1f1e` you need to swap the two bytes. You can of course also use `sta ($00, x)` assuming `x` is zero.

Comment: @Jester I'd promote that to an answer if I were you; it clearly answers the question and will be more prominent to people who find this question in the future. Failing that I guess somebody else could post it as community wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with 16-bit quantities, you need to make sure your variables are 16 bits, or 2 bytes wide.

You probably want to use the 6502 little-endian order, especially if your variable could be used as an address.  That means *low-byte, high-byte* order.

> I have a number 1f stored at address 00, and I have another number 1e stored at address 01.

You really want to have $001F stored at address $00-$01 ($00 will equal #$1F and $01 will equal #$00), and $001E stored at address $02-$03 ($02 will equal #$1E and $03 will equal #$00).  Then you probably want another variable to hold the result, let's say $04-$05.

---

But, if you really have two 8-bit variables and you want to "convert" them to 16-bit variables ...

Assume (using labels for clarity):

$00 - your first 8-bit variable (label `VAR_A_8`)

$01 - your second 8-bit variable (label `VAR_B_8`)

$02-$03 - where you want to place your first converted 8-bit variable (label `VAR_A_16`)

$04-$05 - where you want to place your second converted 8-bit variable (label `VAR_B_16`)

**Are they *unsigned*?**  If so, just `LDA #$00, STA VAR_A_16, STA VAR_B_16, LDA $00, >STA VAR_A_16, LDA $01, STA >VAR_B_16`.

The `>` is a common assembler syntax to mean "low byte of" (It *might* actually be `<` - I always got confused on that)

**Are they *signed*?** If the 8-bit values are negative (bit 7 set), you want to store $FF in the new bytes, otherwise you want to store $00.

One way:

```
               LDX #$00
               LDA VAR_A_8       ;Loading .A will set N flag in .P if bit 7 is set
               BPL VAR_A_NOT_NEG
               DEX               ;.X will now be $FF
VAR_A_NOT_NEG: STX <VAR_A_16     ;store .X in high byte
               STA >VAR_A_16     ;copy low byte
               LDX #$00
               LDA VAR_B_8
               BPL VAR_B_NOT_NEG
               DEX
VAR_B_NOT_NEG: STX <VAR_B_16
               STA >VAR_B_16
```

Answer (score 1):

The 6502 is an 8-bit machine; it constructs 16-bit quantities by reading the least significant byte from the lower address (i.e. it is little endian).

You therefore just need to put the `1e` into an address before `1f` — by switching them around versus your current layout, by moving `1f` to address `02` or by some other means. No shifting or ORing is necessary; indeed there is no 16-bit register inside the 6502 that can be shifted or operated upon with bitwise logic.

If the two bytes are kept at `00` and `01` but reversed then you can e.g. zero out `x` and use the `($00, x)` addressing mode to access `1f1e`.